# The Complex Power from a source V = 200cos(wt) is 200 + j150. The impedance across V is given by what value?

Tags: power, ac

I found the answer using P = V^2/R and by using P = VI*. In both cases, I got the answer as 128 + 96j. But the answer given is 64 + 48j. Which is the correct answer?

Comment: Your solution seems wrong ,P = V^2/R this can be used when V is voltage across R but in this question there is reactance as well which causes voltage drop across it also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one writes \$V=200\cos(\omega t)\$, \$V\$ is the *instantaneous* voltage, and 200 is the *peak* of that voltage. To calculate *power* you need to use the rms value the voltage, which for a sine wave is \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = 0.707\$ times the peak voltage.

The failure to use rms value is why the answer you arrived at is twice as large as the correct answer.

The complex power \$S\$ is given by:

\$S = V_{rms}\cdot I_{rms}^*\$

so

\$I_{rms}= \frac{S^*}{V_{rms}^*}\$

The impedance is given by

\$Z = \frac{V}{I} = \frac{V_{rms}}{I_{rms}} = \frac{V_{rms}V_{rms}^*}{S^*}\$

In the given problem,

\$Z = \frac{(\frac{ 200}{\sqrt{2}})^2}{200-j150}= \frac{20000}{200^2+150^2}(200+j150)=\frac{20000}{62500}(200+j150) = 64+j48\$